# How to crop image using Rectangle?

Tags: image-processing

I use `ImageBoundingBoxes` to get the bounding boxes of objects in an image. I then want to crop out each object and I tried directly passing the Rectangle objects from `ImageBoundingBoxes` to `ImageTake`, but it does not work. I also tried converting the rectangle to a list of points by doing

```
{rect[[1]],rect[[2]]}
```

and passing that to `ImageTake`, but that also did not work, probably because `ImageTake` expects row and col number, which start from the top left corner, whereas `Rectangle` contains x and y which start from the bottom left corner. How can I convert `Rectangle` to a form that I can pass to `ImageTake` so that I can crop out the part of the image that the bounding box covers?

EDIT:
I looked at ImageTrim and wrote the following function to to get a list of the four corners of a Rectangle object so that it can be passed to ImageTrim:

```
rectToList[rect_] := {rect[[1]], rect[[2]], {rect[[1, 1]], rect[[2, 2]]}, {rect[[2, 1]], rect[[1, 2]]}};
```

Then, I was able to crop out the bounding box portion as follows:

```
croppedImg = ImageTrim[img,rectToList[rect]];
```

Is this the best way to crop out the bounding box portion of an image?

Comment: Have you seen [`ImageTrim`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTrim.html)?

Comment: @C.E. Thank you for the suggestion. ImageTrim requires a list of points, so I wrote a simple function that makes a list of the four corners of the rectangle. Is this the best way?

Comment: I think it can work to pass the rectangles. `ImageTrim` can, as the documentation says, take a region of interest (or a list of regions). Consider the examples under "Application" for example. Say, the `FindFaces` example. `FindFaces` returns `Rectangle` objects and yet it works.

Comment: @C.E. Yes, you are right. I forgot that FindFaces returned Rectangle. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As C.E. noted, easiest way is to use `ImageTrim[image, rectangles]` as `ImageTrim` accepts `Rectangle` objects as the trimming spec.

You can also to use [`ImageTake`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTake.html) by converting rectangle coordinates to a form that can be used row and column specs in `ImageTake`:

```
ClearAll[imageTake]

imageTake[im_, r : {__Rectangle}] :=  Module[{rowscols = 
    Map[Apply[{ImageDimensions[im][[2]] + 1 - Reverse@#, #2} &]@* Reverse@*Transpose]@
      (r /. Rectangle -> List)}, 
    ImageTake[im, ##] & @@@ rowscols]
```

**Example:** Using the image from the first example in [`ImageBoundingBoxes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageBoundingBoxes.html):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xQHy.png"]
```

[image]

```
rectangles = ImageBoundingBoxes[img, Entity["Species", "Class:Aves"]]
```

> ```
>  {Rectangle[{130.885, 18.5558}, {166.549, 92.807}], 
>   Rectangle[{91.2438, 38.0867}, {130.923, 101.634}]}
> ```

```
imageTake[img, rectangles] // Map[ImageResize[#, 300] &]
```

[image]

We get the same result using `ImageTrim` directly with `rectangles`:

```
ImageTrim[img, rectangles] // Map[ImageResize[#, 300] &]
```

> ```
>  same picture.
> ```